# Добавление библиотеки QuaZip5 в cmake-проект на Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake

Пытаюсь подключить к существующему Windows-cmake проекту библиотеку QuaZip.
Библиотека прекрасно собралась штатными средствами (библиотека в своем составе имеет Cmake-файл, описывающий её как проект).
После сборки библиотеки, в каталоге сборки выполнил cmake_install.cmake скрипт, после чего собранная библиотека установилась в "C:\Program Files (x86)\QuaZip" (путь по-умолчанию).
В cmake-файл моего проекта добавил

```
find_package(QuaZip5)
```

Однако проект не собирается: cmake не может найти конфигурацию для QuaZip5:

```
CMake Error at E:/progs/qt/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/mingw73_32/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5QuaZip5" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5QuaZip5Config.cmake
    qt5quazip5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5QuaZip5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5QuaZip5_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5QuaZip5" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Я понимаю, что в переменной окружения Qt5QuaZip5_DIR необходимо указать путь к конфигурационным файлам библиотеки, но в составе самой либы их нет.
Не подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54223593/13970074

Comment: @dIm0n Ох, спасибо. 
Проблема была в том, что составил строку find_package неверно.
нужно добавлять 
find_package(QuaZip5) отдельной строкой, а не добавлять в уже существующую.
Спасибо за наводку!

Answer (score 1):

Решение: Для корректного добавления библиотеки в проект необходимо использовать директиву `find_package` следующим образом: вместо дополнения уже существующего аргумента директивы `find_package` необходимо добавить еще одно выражение

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Xml REQUIRED)
find_package(QuaZip5)
```

Comment: я только не понял почему у вас вопрсе написано, что вы эту строку `find_package(QuaZip5)` добавили, хотя это не соответствует ни приведенным логам, ни вашему же ответу...